# Why Ubuntu isn't installed in UEFI by default?

Tags: uefi

I have seen some posts about installing Ubuntu in BIOS and in UEFI. In the Community Wiki mentions that UEFI will replace the BIOS in all PCs. Also it mentions that if it is not absolutely necessary we should install Ubuntu in BIOS and not UEFI.

Windows 8.1 to my understanding already are installed only in UEFI. So my question is why Ubuntu isn't installed in UEFI by default (like Windows 8.1) if UEFI is going to be the replacement of BIOS?

Moreover Ubuntu not only isn't installed by default in UEFI but installing in it is discouraged (in the Community Wiki). Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd first like to reiterate what kos wrote: The Ubuntu installer installs Ubuntu in the mode in which it was booted. You as a user have no choice on the matter *once the installer has booted.* Your only choice in the matter comes *before* that point, when you boot the medium. Unfortunately, how to force the medium to boot in a particular mode varies from one computer to another, so it's difficult to describe succinctly and in a way that's universally applicable.

The Ubuntu installer could, in theory, install a BIOS-mode boot loader when booted in EFI mode; but it cannot *fully* install an EFI-mode boot loader when booted in BIOS mode. The reason is that EFI boot loaders rely on NVRAM settings that can only be manipulated from an EFI-mode boot. This, really, is the reason for linking the installation mode to the boot mode.

As to why the wiki discourages installation in EFI mode, you'd have to ask its authors. Personally, I think that detail is wrong. ***VERY*** wrong. (I also never noticed it before now. Maybe it's relatively new.) In a dual-boot configuration, the Ubuntu boot mode should be matched to the boot mode of whatever OS is already installed on the computer. Doing it otherwise requires jumping through post-installation hoops to either synchronize the two boot modes or to create a way to easily switch boot modes on a per-boot basis. In fact, I've written [a Web page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) that provides my own advice. It's not Ubuntu-specific, but it applies quite well to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu automatically detects whether a machine has been booted in legacy mode or in UEFI mode and chooses the installation type based on that.

So the installation type is determined based on how the installer has been booted.

So this is really dependant on the UEFI settings rather than on how Ubuntu is designed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Ubuntu's live media does boot and install in UEFI mode when
the machine is in UEFI mode.  The problem is each vendor seems to
put their own non-UEFI standard tweaks into the UEFI boot process,
so each machine has it unique set of issues when installing in
UEFI mode.  When Windows 8.1 is installed in UEFI mode, that is the
necessary condition to use UEFI mode for Ubuntu.  If you are just
putting Ubuntu on a machine without Windows, there is no reason
to put up with all the vendor nonsense, just switch over to
compatibility/legacy/BIOS mode and install works as it always has.
It doesn't hurt to try a straight UEFI install even it that case.
Some machines which follow the UEFI standard will install in UEFI
mode  just as easily as the BIOS/legacy installs.